# build_runner not creating file

Tags: flutter, hive

I am following a tutorial to cache an api responce using hive.

Below is the code which has *part 'posts_model.g.dart';* in it, but the build runner is giving me this message and not creating the file.

> [WARNING] source_gen:combining_builder on lib/posts_model_dart.dart:
> posts_model_dart.g.dart must be included as a part directive in the
> input library with:
> part 'posts_model_dart.g.dart';

It seems to be telling me that I need this *part 'posts_model.g.dart';*, which I have

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';

part 'posts_model.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class PostsModel {
  @HiveField(0)
  final int? userId;
  @HiveField(1)
  final int? id;
  @HiveField(2)
  final String? title;
  @HiveField(3)
  final String? body;

  PostsModel({
    this.userId,
    this.id,
    this.title,
    this.body,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return <String, dynamic>{
      'userId': userId,
      'id': id,
      'title': title,
      'body': body,
    };
  }

  factory PostsModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return PostsModel(
      userId: map['userId'] != null ? map['userId'] as int : null,
      id: map['id'] != null ? map['id'] as int : null,
      title: map['title'] != null ? map['title'] as String : null,
      body: map['body'] != null ? map['body'] as String : null,
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory PostsModel.fromJson(String source) =>
      PostsModel.fromMap(json.decode(source) as Map<String, dynamic>);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file name is `posts_model_dart.dart`, not `posts_model.dart`. So the part line should be:

```dart
part 'posts_model_dart.g.dart';
```

Alternatively you might want to actually rename the file to `posts_model.dart` because that seems redundant :)